# How to specify bitrate for an AudioStreamBasicDescription in coreaudio?

Tags: ios, core-audio

I'm recording some PCM audio using an Audio Unit. In the callback, when I have 30 seconds of audio, I want to write to disk an 8000Hz AAC encoded file with a 12kb/s bitrate.

This is the AudioStreamBasicDescription that I use, but my output ends up being 40 kb/s. My question is, can I change some parameters to lower the bitrate, and if so, which parameters do I modify?

```
    // specify the M4A
    AudioStreamBasicDescription outputFormat = {0};

    outputFormat.mSampleRate         = 8000.0;
    outputFormat.mFormatID           = kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC;
    outputFormat.mFormatFlags        = kMPEG4Object_AAC_Main;
    outputFormat.mChannelsPerFrame   = 1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the field `mBitsPerChannel` in the AudioStreamBasicDescription.

> The number of bits for one audio sample. For example, for linear PCM audio using the kAudioFormatFlagsCanonical format flags, calculate the value for this field as follows:

```
mBitsPerChannel = 8 * sizeof (AudioSampleType);
```

> Set this field to 0 for compressed formats.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/CoreAudioDataTypesRef/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/AudioStreamBasicDescription

Comment: This sets the bit depth, but not the bit rate, correct? Bit depth is something like 16 bits or 24 bits, while bit rate is something like 128kbps

Comment: @user1021430, I agree with you. Do you know the right way to set the bitrate?

Answer (score -1):

The bit rate is equal to `sampleRate * bitDepth * numberOfChannel`, that's way you can set your bit rate by choosing the right value for this 3 variables.
For a Wave of 44100kHz, 16bit per sample and stereo you will have:
`16 * 44100 * 2 = 1 411 200 bit/sec`

Comment: The question is about compressed audio format, not PCM. The bitDepth is irrelevant here